# Entity Framework Queries For Complicated JSON Documents (npgsql)

Tags: json, entity-framework, npgsql

I am handling legacy (old) JSON files that we are now uploading to a database that was built using code-first EF Core (with the JSON elements saved as a jsonb field in a postgresql db, represented as JsonDocument properties in the EF classes).  We want to be able to query these massive documents against any of the JSON's many properties. I've been very interested in the excellent docs here https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html?tabs=data-annotations%2Cpoco, but the problem in our case is that our JSON has incredibly complicated hierarchies.

According to the npgsql/EF doc above, a way to do this for "shallow" json hierarchies would be something like:

myDbContext.MyClass
.Where(e => e.JsonDocumentField.RootElement.GetProperty("FieldToSearch").GetString() == "SearchTerm")
.ToList();

But that only works if  is directly under the root of the JSONDocument. If the doc is structed like, say

```
 {"A": {
   ...
     "B": {
       ...
          "C": {
            ...
               "FieldToSearch":
    <snip>
```

Then the above query won't work. There is an alternative to map our JSON to an actual POCO model, but this JSON structure (a) may change and (b) is truly massive and would result in some ridiculously complicated objects.

Right now, I'm building SQL strings using field configurations where I save strings to find the fields I want using psql's JSON querying language
Example:
"(JSONDocumentField->'A'->'B'->'C'->>'FieldToSearch')"

and then using that sql against the DB using

myDbContext.MyClass.FromSqlRaw(sql).ToList();

This is hacky and I'd much rather do it in a method call. Is there a way to force JsonDocument's GetProperty call to drill down into the hierarchy to find the first/any instance of the property name in question (or another method I'm not aware of)?

Thanks!

Comment: Querying with GetProperty in LINQ should work regardless of how deep the hierarchy is... Have you tried chaining multiple GetProperty() calls?

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. Do you mean (using the above example) e.JsonDocumentField.RootElement.GetProperty("A").GetProperty("B").GetProperty("C").GetProperty("FieldToSearch").GetString() == "SearchTerm" ?

I imagine that would work, but I was hoping to do it in a way that is agnostic of the hierarchy of the document- that FieldToSearch could be at the top level or 10 deep and it would still be found.

Comment: If you're looking to find any JSON property with a given key - regardless of where exactly it is in the JSON tree - then that's a very different question from what you posted above... What should be the behavior if there's more than one?

Comment: You may be able to express this via JSONPATH, see [the PG docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH). If so, then you can drop down to a SQL query and do it that way (I do plan to add support for executing arbitrary JSONPATH queries without SQL queries).

Comment: Apologies for the miscommunication- I am mostly interested in ANY property value that matches a given search parameter. I'll read up on JSONPATH. Thanks again!